# Как узнать поисковую фразу пользователя из яндекс/гугл аналитики

Tags: php, google-analytics, yandex-metrika-api

Есть задача: получить поисковую фразу, которую ввёл пользователь в яндекс или гугл, нашёл нужный сайт и перешёл на него. Записать эту поисковую фразу куда-нибудь в базу и далее выставлять отчёт такого типа:

1. Фраза: "тракторы калуга", Количество пользователей по фразе: 4, Количество зарегистрированных по фразе: 1.
2. Фраза: "запчасти к трактору белаз", Количество пользователей по фразе: 9, Количество зарегистрированных по фразе: 2.

и так далее

К сайту подключены яндекс и гугл аналитики. Возможно ли реализовать такую задачу? Есть ли решение на js/php (как получить поисковую фразу), или нужно использовать API аналитики?

Comment: а как вы себе представляете решение этой задачи без использования API этих сервисов?

Comment: Я для этого и задаю вопрос чтобы узнать как решить задачу. Я бы не задавал вопрос если бы знал решение задачи

Comment: дак если сервисы предоставляют API, то конечно стоит их использовать. зачем еще какие то костыли придумывать.

Comment: вопрос не в том "что использовать" вопрос стоит "как решить задачу". просмотрел возможности api и не увидел там никакой привязки поисковой фразы к конкретному пользователю. а нужно знать по какой фразе определённый пользователь попал на сайт